# Using Django template tag "with" with the result of another template tag

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I have a `comment_form.html` template, which is used in multiple places in my app, and I'd like to be able to pass the endpoint's url into that template from a parent template.  Normally I would do this using the `with` tag:

```
{% with endpoint='/comments' %}
    {% include 'comment_form.html' %}
{% endwith %}
```

The problem is that I can't use a string literal `'/comments'` here, but instead I need a url tag, like so: `{% url 'blog:comments:comments' username=post.user.username object_id=post.id %}`.  The `with` template tag seems to expects a literal or a context variable and doesn't seem to be able to comprehend "use the result of another template tag".

One solution would be to pass the strings 'blog:comments:comments', post.user.username, post.id all separately.  But this is a problem because different uses of the comment form may require different arguments to uniquely define the endpoint.

How can I use `with` with the result of another template tag?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't, but you don't need to. The `url` tag has an alternative syntax that injects is result into the context:

```
{% url 'blog:comments:comments' username=post.user.username object_id=post.id as endpoint %}
```

Comment: This is perfect!  I combed over the docs for `with` and similar tags but I never thought to really look at the `url` tag itself.  Thanks a lot.